Problem with sum of the series
I have been studying the Digital Control of Dynamic Systems third edition by Gene F. Franklin, J. David Powell, Michael Workmann. There is an equation which I don't understand in the Chapter 12 on page 512. Namely my problem is the below given equation (12.21)

At first I don't understand why the term $\frac{1}{N}$ is missing at the right hand side in the first row. Let's suppose that the missing term is correct then I still don't understand the second row. May I ask for explanation? Thank you in advance.

You are correct. The term $\frac{1}{N}$ is missing in the first line of equation $(12.21)$. The correct expression is:
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{-j2\pi lk/N} = \frac{1-e^{-j2\pi l}}{N(1-e^{-j2\pi l/N})}$$
This equation holds true only when $e^{-j2\pi l/N} \neq 1$, so the denominator won't go to zero. When $e^{-j2\pi l/N} = 1$ or equivalently, when $l/N$ is an integer, you have $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{-j2\pi lk/N} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}1 = \frac{N}{N} = 1$$
This explains the firs part of the second line.
If $l/N$ is not an integer, then $e^{-j2\pi l/N} \neq 1$ and so the denominator of the expression, $N(1-e^{-j2\pi l/N})$ is non zero, and the fraction makes sense (is defined). In this case, since $l$ is an integer, $1-e^{-j2\pi l} = 0$. Hence the second case of your last equation.
